# Procedure working with query as a parameter in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm currently using this code to generate an XLS file from a query in Oracle PL/SQL saving a file with HTML tags using this code.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GENERATE_XLS(querie VARCHAR2) IS
v_file               VARCHAR2 (20)            := 'TEST-EXCEL.xls';
v_directory            VARCHAR2 (60)            := 'C:\';
p_write                LIB_FILES.file_type;
v_sql varchar2(32767) := 'SELECT LASTNAME, NAME, ID
                                FROM DUAL';
header VARCHAR(1000) := '<html> <head><center><B><U> TEST XLS  </U></B></center>
    <table></tr><tr><th>LASTNAME</th><th>NAME</th><th>ID</th></tr>';
BEGIN    
    p_write := LIB_FILES.fopen (v_directory, v_file, 'W');
    LIB_FILES.put_line (p_write, header);
    FOR REGISTRY IN querie LOOP
        LIB_FILES.put_line (p_write,'<tr><td>'||REGISTRY.LASTNAME||'</td><td>'||REGISTRY.NAME||'</td><td>'||REGISTRY.ID||'</td></tr>');
    END LOOP;
    LIB_FILES.put_line (p_write,'</table>');
    LIB_FILES.fflush (p_write);
    LIB_FILES.fclose (p_write);        
END;
```

This is working right now, but I need to add to this procedure a parameter, which is an SQL query, and then generate the file based on the query

I'm currently use this code to get the columns name

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GET_COLUMNS IS        
    v_cursor_id integer;    
    v_col_cnt integer;
    v_columns dbms_sql.desc_tab;    
    v_sql varchar2(3000) :='SELECT LASTNAME, NAME, ID FROM DUAL';
    header VARCHAR(1000):='<html> <head><center><B><U> TEST XLS  </U></B></center>
    <table></tr><tr>';
begin    
    v_cursor_id := dbms_sql.open_cursor;
    dbms_sql.parse(v_cursor_id, v_sql, dbms_sql.native);
    dbms_sql.describe_columns(v_cursor_id, v_col_cnt, v_columns);
    for i in 1 .. v_columns.count loop
        header := header || '<th>'|| v_columns(i).col_name ||'</th>';        
    end loop;
    header := header || '</tr>';

    dbms_sql.close_cursor(v_cursor_id);
exception when others then
    dbms_sql.close_cursor(v_cursor_id);
    raise;
end;
```

But here I'm facing the same issue, I need to make this procedures works with dynamic queries coming from a parameter instead of declaring the query in the procedure.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have oracle installed , as of my knowledge I gave these details ... check and verify this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GET_COLUMNS (p_sql IN VARCHAR2 , p_header IN VARCHAR2)

IS        
    v_cursor_id integer;    
    v_col_cnt integer;
    v_columns dbms_sql.desc_tab;    
    v_sql varchar2(3000) := p_sql;
    header VARCHAR(1000):= p_header;
begin    
    v_cursor_id := dbms_sql.open_cursor;
    dbms_sql.parse(v_cursor_id, v_sql, dbms_sql.native);
    dbms_sql.describe_columns(v_cursor_id, v_col_cnt, v_columns);
    for i in 1 .. v_columns.count loop
        header := header || '<th>'|| v_columns(i).col_name ||'</th>';        
    end loop;
    header := header || '</tr>';

    dbms_sql.close_cursor(v_cursor_id);
exception when others then
    dbms_sql.close_cursor(v_cursor_id);
    raise;
end;

To execute 

Execute GET_COLUMNS ('SELECT LASTNAME, NAME, ID FROM DUAL','<html> <head><center><B><U> TEST XLS  </U></B></center>
    <table></tr><tr>');
```

Comment: I just saw , by giving whole html in single parameter TEST XLS changed to test xls ...by making as 3 parameter and by contact of 2 nd and 3rd parameter as one  CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GET_COLUMNS (p_sql IN VARCHAR2 , p_header1 IN VARCHAR2,p_header2 IN VARCHAR2)

IS

v_sql varchar2(3000) := p_sql;
v_header VARCHAR(1000):= p_header1||' ' ||'TEST XLS'||' ' ||p_header2;
 
 BEGIN
 
 dbms_output.put_line ( v_header);
 
 END;   Execute GET_COLUMNS ('SELECT LASTNAME, NAME, ID FROM DUAL' , '<html> <head><center><B><U>','</U></B></center><table></tr><tr');

Answer (score 1):

If you define your query as a ref cursor instead of a string, e.g.

```
open your_refcursor for select * from dual;
```

then you can convert it to a dbms_sql cursor ID using

```
v_cursor_id := dbms_sql.to_cursor_number(your_refcursor);
```

Here is one I wrote earlier:

http://www.williamrobertson.net/documents/refcursor-to-csv.shtml

Answer (score 0):

I suggest read the following article, about a package to create Excel files from Oracle:

[Create an Excel-file with PL/SQL](https://technology.amis.nl/2011/02/19/create-an-excel-file-with-plsql/)